# Refresh stepper value

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol, uistepper

I have 3 segmented control (game names), and 3 text fields for price, quantity, subtotal. Also I have 1 stepper to increase or decrease quantity between 1 and 5.

My problem appears when I change quantity for 1 game and change choose another game. Lets assume I increase game1 quantity to 5 and change game. Quantity field set to 1 automatically. But "+" in stepper is non-selectable and when I press "-" in stepper quantity is getting 4.

I thing what i need is to refresh stepper value when i change game from segmented control. Any idea ?

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var Photo: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var seg_games: UISegmentedControl!
        @IBOutlet weak var lbl_motto: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var txt_unitPrice: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var txt_quantity: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var txt_totalPrice: UITextField!
        @IBOutlet weak var step_qChooser: UIStepper!


        @IBAction func stepChanged(sender: UIStepper) {


            if (txt_quantity.text.isEmpty) {
                let alert = UIAlertView()
                alert.title = "No Game Choose"
                alert.message = "Please Pick Your Game First !"
                alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
                alert.show()
            }

            else {

            txt_quantity.text = Int(sender.value).description
            txt_totalPrice.text = TotalCalc()

            }
        }

        func TotalCalc () -> String {
            var a = txt_unitPrice.text.toInt()
            var b = txt_quantity.text.toInt()
            var sonuc = a! * b!
            return String(sonuc)
        }


        @IBAction func seg_games(sender: AnyObject) {

            var index = seg_games.selectedSegmentIndex
            var choice = seg_games.titleForSegmentAtIndex(index)!

            if choice == "Fallout"
            {
                lbl_motto.text = "Be Prepare your P.I.M.P."
                self.Photo.image = UIImage(named: "fallout.png")
                txt_quantity.text = "1"
                txt_unitPrice.text = "80"

                txt_totalPrice.text = TotalCalc()

            }

            else if choice == "Borderlands"
            {
                lbl_motto.text = "Ready for BIG BOYS !!!"
                self.Photo.image = UIImage(named: "borderlands.png")
                txt_quantity.text = "1"
                txt_unitPrice.text = "55"

                txt_totalPrice.text = TotalCalc()

            }

            else if choice == "Battlefield"

            {
                lbl_motto.text = "Choose: Sniper or Assult"
                self.Photo.image = UIImage(named: "battlefield.png")
                txt_quantity.text = "1"
                txt_unitPrice.text = "110"

                txt_totalPrice.text = TotalCalc()

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` of a `UIStepper` is both readable and writable.

If you always want the quantity to return to `1` when you change segments, then just set the stepper value to `1.0` when you change segments:

```
step_qChooser.value = 1.0
```

---

If you want the quantity to stick (e.g. the quantity of Borderlands stays at `3` if you switch away and come back), you need to store the quantities of each item separately from the `UIStepper`.

1. Create an array to hold the stepper values.  This is a property of your `ViewController`, so it should be defined above any of the methods:

   ```
   var quantities = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
   ```

   These quantities will be indexed by the `index` that you get from the `UISegmentedControl`.
2. When a new game is selected, update the stepper value from the quantities and set the text field accordingly:

   ```
   step_qChooser.value = quantities[index]
   txt_quantity.text = "\(Int(quantities[index]))"
   ```
3. When the stepper value changes, be sure to update the values in the `quantities` array.  Inside the `stepChanged()` function do:

   ```
   quantities[seg_games.selectedSegmentIndex] = step_qChooser.value
   ```

Comment: works like a charm!! I was trying to set the value of action instead of outlet.value . Thanks a lot.